# phonegap android-studio/sdk/tools/ant/build.xml:932: The following error occurred while executing this line:

Tags: angularjs, cordova, yeoman

I'm following the good tutorial at
http://briantford.com/blog/angular-phonegap.html

but when I run

cordova build android

I've got the error in the Title :(

Can you give me an hint on what's going on, please ?

Comment: Don't think the title includes enough of the error output to be helpful.  It says it ran into an error while executing this line: but doesn't indicate what the error was... is it actually blank in the output if so would help to clarify that